# Add an element into xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, oop, netbeans

I have a problem with php and xml files: I want to add an element into xml file. I've wrote this code and it works:

```
<?php

$file = 'clients.xml';                

$doc = new DOMDocument();                 
$doc->load($file);                       
$get_elms = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Client");     
$nr_elms = $get_elms->length;             

$node = $get_elms->item($nr_elms-1);              
$element = $node->nodeName;               

if($element=='Client') {
    $idfinal=intval($node->getAttribute('id'))+1;
    $client = $doc->createElement('Client');                          
    $node->parentNode->appendChild($client);   
    $client->setAttribute('id',$idfinal);    
    $client->setAttribute('name','Any name');
    $client->setAttribute('cnp','12345');
    $client->setAttribute('adress','adress');
    $client->setAttribute('nb','123');
    $client->setAttribute('amount','1000');
    $client->setAttribute('type','Any type');

 }


if($doc->save('clients.xml')) {
echo htmlentities($doc->saveXML());
}


?>
```

If I put exactly the same code into a class, into function addClient it doesn't work because it doesn't recognize my xml file. I've tried echo $get_elms->length; and it returns me 0 and my variable $element is empty so it does not enter in that "if". I need to use this class because I must do more operations like delete and update and I must send some parameters to those functions. Can anyone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong?

My class looks like this:

```
class xmlClientMappers {


    public function adaugaClient(array $row)
    {

        $name    = $row['name'];
        $adress  = $row['adress'];
        $cnp     = $row['cnp'];
        $nb      = $row['nb'];
        $amount  = $row['amount'];
        $type    = $row['type'];

      $file = 'clients.xml';                

$doc = new DOMDocument();                 
$doc->load($file);                       
$get_elms = $doc->getElementsByTagName("*");     
$nr_elms = $get_elms->length;             
echo "The nomber is ".$nr_elms;
$node = $get_elms->item($nr_elms-1);              
$element = $node->nodeName;               
echo "<br/>Here should be the name of the last element".$element;
if($element=='Client') {
    $idfinal=intval($node->getAttribute('id'))+1;
    echo " id-ul e ".$idfinal;
    $client = $doc->createElement('Client');                          
    $node->parentNode->appendChild($client);   
    $client->setAttribute('id',$idfinal);    
    $client->setAttribute('name',$name);
    $client->setAttribute('cnp',$cnp);
    $client->setAttribute('adress',$adress);
    $client->setAttribute('nb',$nb);
    $client->setAttribute('amount',$amount);
    $client->setAttribute('type',$type);

}


     if($doc->save('clienti.xml')) {
       echo htmlentities($doc->saveXML());
  else echo "It is wrong!";
}
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$get_elms = $doc->getElementsByTagName("*");  ` you changed it from `$get_elms = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Client");`

Comment: If I let $doc->getElementsByTagName("Client"); it still does not work.

Comment: is `clients.xml` in the same location as the script that uses this class?

Comment: A moment ago I realize this thing. I have saved my xml file in the same folder with my class, not in the location that uses it. Thank for your answer anyway!

Comment: Haha, it's always a good thing when the solution turns out to be a simple oversight. =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put the xml location relative to the location of the file that executes the request.

so for example folowing structure:

```
lib
  \ xmlClientMappers.php
  \ client.xml
index.php
```

you would have to use "./lib/client.xml" for your filename.

I assume this will be the problem.